# Может ли java.util.Properties.entrySet содержать нулевые значения?

Tags: java, null, проверка, properties

В старом коде встретилось место с большим количеством проверок на null при итерации по еntrySet в java.util.Properties:

```java
private void createMaps(java.util.Properties properties)
{
    for(Entry<Object, Object> entry : properties.entrySet())
    {
        if(null == entry) continue;

        if(null == entry.getKey() || null == entry.getValue()) continue;

        String propertyKey = entry.getKey().toString();
        String propertyValue = entry.getValue().toString();

        if(null == propertyKey || null == propertyValue) continue;

        // ...
    }
}
```

В связи с чем возникло несколько вопросов - может ли возникнуть ситуация, когда:

1. entry равен null?
2. возвращаемое значение entry.getKey()/entry.getValue() равно null?
3. результат преобразования к строке entry.getKey/getValue().toString() равно null?

Не знаю, относится ли это к вопросу, но лучше уточню, что properties грузятся из файла с расширением .properties так:

```java
public static Properties getProperties(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath))
    {
        properties.load(fis);
    }
    return properties;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ветеранский" класс `Properties` унаследован от "ветеранского" класса `Hashtable`, который появился ещё в Java 1.0, и который *разрешает* [любые не-`null` объекты](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) в качестве ключей или значений хэш-таблицы:

> This class implements a hash table, which maps keys to values. Any non-null object can be used as a key or as a value.

`null` могут использоваться в качестве ключа и/или значений в классе [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> *Hash table based implementation of the `Map` interface. This implementation provides all of the optional map operations, and permits `null` values and the `null` key. (The `HashMap` class is roughly equivalent to `Hashtable`, except that it is unsynchronized and permits nulls.)*

Кроме того, класс `Properties` в качестве ключей и значений содержит [только объекты класса `String`](Each key and its corresponding value in the property list is a string.):

> *Each key and its corresponding value in the property list is a string.*

Поэтому проверка на `null` в данном случае совершенно лишняя, так как свойства загружаются из файла, и будут содержать только пары строк `"ключ" = "значение"`

В показанном коде `null` могут проявиться только в случае "несанкционированного" использования методов `put / putAll` с некими объектами, которые будут возвращать `null` из своего метода `toString()`, но попытка сохранить такие свойства вызовет исключение:

> *If the `store` or `save` method is called on a "compromised" Properties object that contains a non-String key or value, the call will fail. Similarly, the call to the `propertyNames` or `list` method will fail if it is called on a "compromised" Properties object that contains a non-String key.*